# How can I separate a column in new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't know how to ask this question, but i'll try do explain my case.

I have a dataset with the data as following:

| Product | Value | Value type | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 21,5 | Price | 21 |
| A | 5 | Volume | 21 |
| B | 55,3 | Price | 21 |
| B | 10 | Volume | 21 |
| C | 70,0 | Price | 21 |
| D | 37,5 | Price | 21 |
| D | 7,7 | Volume | 21 |

And I want to reach something like that:

| Product | Price | Volume | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 21,5 | 5 | 21 |
| B | 55,3 | 10 | 21 |
| c | 70,0 | - | 21 |
| D | 37,0 | 7,7 | 21 |

I mind that the unstack function can solve the problem, but i don't know how, cause i'm not getting all the columns back.

I found a complex solution but it's not working.

```
container = []
for label, _df in df.groupby(['Year','Product']):
  _df.set_index('Value type', inplace = True)
  container.append(pd.DataFrame({
                        "Product": [label[1]],
                        "Price":[_df.loc['Price', 'Value']],
                        "Volume": [_df.loc['Volume', 'Value']],
                        "Year":[label[0]]}))

df_new = pd.concat(container)
```

This solution doesn't work, because the missing line for Volume for product C.

How can I reach the expected dataframe?
Is there any fast way to calculate this?

Comment: It looks like [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) -> `df.pivot(index=['Product', 'year'], columns='Value type', values=['Value'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot`:

```
out = df.pivot(index=['Product', 'year'], columns='Value type', values=['Value']) \
        .droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1) \
        [['Product', 'Price', 'Volume', 'year']]
```

```
>>> out
  Product  Price  Volume  year
0       A   21.5     5.0    21
1       B   55.3    10.0    21
2       C   70.0     NaN    21
3       D   37.5     7.7    21
```